# Creating a .oft outlook file in windows 10 that will send and open correctly on mac standard email

Tags: macos, email, formatting, dat-protocol, oft

I am creating an outlook email .oft file built with tables on a windows 10 pc using MS Outlook 2016.

I want to be able to send this template as an email over to an apple mac user who can open it on their standard email package.

I have tried and tested this to mac and currently, the sent email to mac is creating a separate .dat file attachment and creating a text version of the email rather than keeping the email table formatting.

I have already tried different email send encodings namely UTF8 and Windows(ISO) and the result is still the same.

Are there any further settings or techniques that I could try to get this working from end to end?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [superuser](https://superuser.com) would be a much more appropriate place to ask about this. But... I'm pretty sure the .oft format is proprietary to MS Outlook, so it's inherently not going to be portable to other platforms (I don't think it's even supported by the Mac version of Outlook).

Comment: Apologies if I posted this in the wrong place but I found an answer, applied it, tested it and it works, so for those who also have the same issue here is the link: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/stop-outlook-sending-winmail-dat-file-email-attachment